# How do you format datetime to 24hours? I have a combobox with time starting at 00:00 in 15min intervals, but it crashes if I pick over 12:00

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, combobox

My actual code is for calculating the time difference between two comboboxes in a 24 hour period and this is the code I have so for it:

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string format = "hh:mm";
        starttime = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox1.Text, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string format = "hh:mm";
        endtime = DateTime.ParseExact(comboBox2.Text, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    }

    private void buttonCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan z;

        z = endtime - starttime;
        textBox1.Text = z.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the format string `HH` instead of `hh` for hours between 0-23. `hh` will only give you the hour 0-11, which is why you get duplicates.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx